# counting file characters with fseek

Tags: c, file-io, fseek

i want to count file chars like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int d=0;
    char filename[25];
    FILE *file;
    printf("Enter file name to be read (Text File!) : ");
    gets(filename);
    file = fopen(filename, "rt");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("Failed to open file...");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    while( !feof(file) ){
        fseek(file, 1L, SEEK_CUR);
        d++;
    }
    printf("%d", d);
}
```

after that im printing d and it value is 0..
and the file dose have chars. about 150 chars..

Comment: What is the `"t"` in the call to `fopen()` for?

Comment: @alk: It's Windows standard for 'text' as opposed to 'binary' file.  It isn't necessary; it is allowed on Windows.

Comment: When I run this on my Debian system, the `while` loop never terminates, because the `fseek()` call doesn't set the file's EOF flag.  (Seeking past the end of a file isn't an error, since you can seek and then write to make the file larger.)

Comment: Ahyes ... that's been looong. Thanks @JonathanLeffler

Comment: _For a text stream, either offset shall be zero, or offset shall be a value returned by
an earlier successful call to the ftell function on a stream associated with the same file
and whence shall be SEEK_SET.,_

Comment: From where please? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @alk [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 7.19.9.2 The fseek function -4

Comment: Interesting, so you want to imply the way the OP uses `fseek()` is undspecified bahaviour? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @alk It is the use of non-standard.

Comment: If the objective is to 'count chars', does it matter if a new line may be represented by 1 or 2 bytes? If no, simply use `fstat` to get the file *length*; if yes, include logic to check each code read.

Comment: "rt" means "read text"

Answer (score 2):

`fseek()` allows you to seek beyond the mark of `EOF`.

To get the file size, you could `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)` and then call `ftell(file)`.

To read character by character, you could use `for (i = 0; fgetc(file) != EOF; i++);`.

Comment: thats the strangest thing. im doing it like that: .. (i dont know how to add code tags...im new)       for (i = 0; fgetc(file) != EOF; i++); and i get i = 0 but there is chars in the file.. is i fwrite it to array then all works great. but i wand to malloc the array.

Comment: @user3423498 worked out well for me. here's the code i tested http://pastebin.com/ej9tyPzL

Comment: did it like you said. fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END) and then call ftell(file).

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if the program ever returns, as per [`fseek()`'s documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) `feof()` shall never return anything  `<>0`:

> A successful call to the
>          fseek() function clears the end-of-file indicator for the stream

---

To determine the file size using `fseek()` do:

```
FILE * pf = ...;

fseek(pf, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(pf);
```

Comment: ...thus making this program just a slightly odd example of [“while( !feof( file ) )” is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: ftell : The return value is implementation-defined if the text stream.

Answer (score 0):

i did it like this at the end and it work.

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
```

and then call
    ftell(file);

befor i tryed to do it like that :

```
for (i = 0; fgetc(file) != EOF; i++);
```

and it didnt worked...but now it is 0.0
Thank you all..!